# How to detect and solve Android's lack of CSS 3D perspective support?

Tags: android, html, css, 3d

I'm trying to build a website using the technique described in this article: [pure CSS parallax](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/).

This technique requires browsers to support 3D transforms (and specifically perspective/preserve 3d).

It's working on the majority of devices and browsers no problem, and where it doesn't it is easy to detect if it'll break (such as lack of `transform-style: preserve-3d` in IE, or lack of 3d transforms at all) and fix it accordingly.

However, one browser stands out in exceptionally f*******g me over when I try and make it compatible to any degree - Android stock browser. Versions of the browser on Android 4+ support css3d transforms but are completely incapable of rendering them properly, with the big bug being that `-webkit-perspective: 1px`, while technically supported has absolutely no effect in this case (`transform: translateZ(xpx)` elements).

As far as I see it I have two options:

1. Detect the Android stock browser and serve CSS accordingly
2. Detect perspective not to be working and serve CSS accordingly (unlikely)

I've yet to find a foolproof/futureproof, elegant way of detecting the Android browser on the back end with PHP, with the only options being hefty API's and what I consider to be lacklustre abuse of mobile detection libraries.

I have absolutely no idea how I'd go about doing no.2.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Doesn't [**Modernizr**](http://modernizr.com/) do this sort of feature detection?

Comment: As far as I know Modernizr doesn't detect buggy implementation of a feature, unfortunately.

Comment: 3rd Option...ignore the stock browser. Does anyone use this anyway? :)

Comment: It still has something like a 20% market share in mobile browsers...

Comment: Since the stock android browser is implementing the feature incorrectly, you might just have to do UA sniffing. But regarding that IE issue, you should check out [this extension to Modernizr](https://coderwall.com/p/qctclg).